# Remove line breaks only if surrounded by quotes

Tags: excel, csv, text, notepad++

I have a large amount of data in a text file that has been giving me some issues.  A lot of the records in the file have line breaks in between the record.  For example this is what my data looks like currently:

```
30670169,           Corvette,   EL-P078675,     EL-P078675, Chevrolet  Corvette C6 Color Matching Millenium Yellow License Plate Frame,     "Made from high-quality billet aluminum, this stylish license frame is custom painted to precisely match the color of your C6 Corvette.

It features an engraved OEM style nameplate. High-gloss finished will never rust.

12"" x 6"" in standard size. Includes color matched screw covers and hardware.

This is a special custom made item. It takes 10-15 business days to ship.

Brand new official licensed product."
```

This is how is should read:

```
30670169,           Corvette,   EL-P078675,     EL-P078675, Chevrolet  Corvette C6 Color Matching Millenium Yellow License Plate Frame,     "Made from high-quality billet aluminum, this stylish license frame is custom painted to precisely match the color of your C6 Corvette. It features an engraved OEM style nameplate. High-gloss finished will never rust. 12"" x 6"" in standard size. Includes color matched screw covers and hardware. This is a special custom made item. It takes 10-15 business days to ship. Brand new official licensed product."
```

I need a method to delete line breaks ONLY if they are surrounded by quotes.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you do View > Show Symbol > End of Line in notepad++, are the end of lines between quotes different from those that indicate the true end of line?

Comment: It has end line symbols where they shouldn't be.  For example it puts end line symbols at the end of "It features an engraved OEM style nameplate. High-gloss finished will never rust." and every following line of my example when the only end of line symbol should appear at "Brand new official licensed product."

Comment: I Excel imports the data into columns properly you may be able to replace the line ends within a column.

Comment: @squid There are different types of end of line. There are carriage returns and line feeds (Windows, unix and mac use different ones sometimes). In notepad, they should appear as CR and/or LF. If you have only LF between quotes and CRLF otherwise, then you could do it in notepad. Or something different, as long as the end of line are different.

Comment: The lines that are broken that aren't supposed to be there are CR's and the ones that are supposed to be there are CRLF's is there a way for me to remove only the CR's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Find/Replace function of Notepad++.

Find:

```
\r(?!\n)
```

Replace with:   (space)

You will need to check the regular expression checkbox:

[image]

Try replacing in a few lines first (select the first 80 lines for example) and then replace in selection just to see. If that works, you can proceed with the whole file.

In the above `\r` will match a CR and `\n` will match an LF. `(?!\n)` is a special group that means 'don't match `\r` if it is followed by `\n`'.

Note: I think that notepad++ sometimes doesn't do the replace correctly, so if replacing the whole file at once cause issues, try replacing in smaller batches.

I usually use a script to do something like this but I don't think you'd be ready to use a script if you're not used to it :s

Answer (score 1):

You can open the csv file in excel and remove line breaks as shown in this link: http://www.excelblog.ca/remove-line-breaks-from-excel-cell/

[image: Some guidelines]

[image: The keyboard shortcut for line breaks]

You can do it on one specific column as well.

Comment: Is there a way for me to do this in a text editor?  The file format I need is .txt and whenever I tried doing that in excel and saving as .txt afterwards puts the line breaks back in.

Comment: You can refer to this link: http://superuser.com/questions/518229/how-to-remove-linebreaks-in-notepad

Or you can also use this online tool. http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php

Comment: Santosh,  I only need the line breaks removed if they are surrounded by quotes.  I have other line breaks in the file that need to be in there.  I've read that superuser page already.

Comment: @squid I recommend doing that in excel then. I could think of coding a script, but that seems long winded.
Steps that come to my mind:
`1.Save as csv,
2. Open in Excel
3. Do your modifications.
4. Save again as csv.
5. Open in notepad to see if it looks okay
6. Save as txt.`

Does that help?

Comment: If you don't need commas, you can copy paste it from excel to notepad directly.